# Incorrect result when adding binary strings

Tags: c

I am getting an incorrect result when adding two binary strings "11" + "11". I am expecting "110" but the answer I am getting is "010". I did add a special case if the carry is still 1.

```
char *addBinary(char *str1, char *str2)
{
    int len1 = strlen(str1); //assume both string lengths are same
    char *res = (char *)malloc((len1 + 1) * sizeof(char));
    int i, a, b;
    int carry = 0;
    char result;
    for (i = len1 - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        a = str1[i] - '0';
        b = str2[i] - '0';
        carry = a + b + carry;
        printf("%d %d %d \n", a, b, carry % 2);
        result = carry % 2 + '0'; //convert to character
        carry = carry / 2;
        str1[i] = result; //use the existing string for the result
    }
    if (carry == 0)
    { //if there is no carry just use the existing string and return
        printf("Final without carry %s \n", str1);
        return str1;
    }
    else
    { //there was a carry, so put 1 in the 0th location and copy the string
        res[0] = 1;
        memcpy(res + 1, str1, sizeof(char) * len1);
        printf("Final %s %s %d\n", res, str1,strlen(res));
        return res;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char bin_str1[] = "11";
    char bin_str2[] = "11";
    printf("%s \n",addBinary(bin_str1, bin_str2));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget that you need enough space for the number to grow by one digit *and* for the null-terminator, so you should allocate `len1+2` bytes with malloc.

Comment: If there is no carry, then str1[0] is uninitialized.

Comment: `res[0] = 1;` should be `res[0] = '1';`

Comment: have you stepped through the code in a debugger?

Comment: You are playing with a dangerous `loop`.  This `for ( i = len1 - 1 ; i >= 0; i--)` where a good compiler should warn you that comparison of unsigned expression `>= 0` is always true in this/your case. Use `i = len -1` and put your code in `while ( i > 0 ){ i-- }` It should be treated as `UB` because if is always TRUE you get yourself in an infinite LOOP.

Comment: `i` and `len1` should be `size_t`. Read about what returns `strlen()` and change `char *res = (char *)malloc( ( len1 + 2 ) * sizeof( char));` to `char *res = malloc( ( len1 + 2 ) * sizeof( *res));`

Comment: You do not need `result`, just use `str1[i] = (char)( carry % 2 + '0');`.

Comment: If you use `calloc( len1, sizeof( *res ) );` instead of `malloc()` call, then this `strcat( res, str1 );` could be easier that this `memcpy(res + 1, str1, sizeof(char) * len1);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two main problems:

First when you allocate space for `res`:

```
char *res = (char *)malloc((len1 + 1) * sizeof(char));
```

You need to allocate space for `len1+2` (carry and `NUL` termination), otherwise your `memcpy` will write out of bounds (you should copy `len1+1` elements, otherwise it is not guaranteed that `res` is `NUL` terminated). Also note that in the case that you return `str1` the memory is leaked.

Second problem occurs when you set the first char of `res` you do net set it to a printable character:

```
res[0] = 1;
```

You should set it to `'1'` instead.

Comment: But what if `len2` is longer than `len1`? So, a third problem: `len2` isn't even defined, much less evaluated or used

Comment: In the original code it is stated `//assume both string lengths are same`, so this is maybe a given constraint, which i also assumed.

Comment: Ah, you see, like the compiler I ignore comments. Even ones that say `//please read this comment` which many effectively do. I like to see constraints and assumptions expressed in code

Comment: @TimRandall I would also prefer to add at least a check `strlen(str1)==strlen(str2)`, rather than trust that the function is called correctly, but I guess it depends ...

Answer (score 1):

One more thing to think of is, that if you have something like this:

```
char bin_str1[] = "10";
char bin_str2[] = "11";
```

Your `addBinary()` Function does not returns `res`, but `str1`.

Now here is the point, if you assign a pointer to your function so that you can release the memory back to the System, you will have an invalid `free()`.

One approach could be like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *addBinary(char *str1, char *str2);

int main( void )
{
    char bin_str1[] = "11";
    char bin_str2[] = "11";
    char *ptr = addBinary( bin_str1, bin_str2 );

    if ( ptr )
    {
        printf("%s \n",ptr );
        free( ptr );
    }
}

char *addBinary(char *str1, char *str2)
{
    char *res = calloc( strlen( str1 ) + strlen( str2 ), sizeof( *res ) );
    int a, b, carry = 0;
    size_t i = strlen( str1 ) - 1;

    while ( i > 0 )
    {
        a = str1[i] - '0';
        b = str2[i] - '0';
        carry += a + b;
        printf("%d %d %d \n", a, b,( carry % 2));
        str1[i] = (char)( carry % 2 + '0'); ///convert to character
        carry = carry / 2;
        i--;
    }
    if ( carry == 0 )
    { ///if there is no carry RETURN NULL
        printf("Final without carry %s \n", str1);
        free( res );
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    { //there was a carry, so put 1 in the 0th location and copy the string
        res[0] = '1';
        strcat( res, str1 );
        printf("Final %s %s %zu\n", res, str1,strlen( res ));
        return res;
    }
}
```

Or, you can drop `malloc` and use it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int addBinary( char *dest, char *const str1, const char *const str2);

int main( void )
{
    char bin_str1[] = "11";
    char bin_str2[] = "11";
    char dest[256] = { 0 };

    if ( addBinary( dest, bin_str1, bin_str2 ) )
    {
        printf("Dest = %s\n", dest );
    }
}

int addBinary( char *dest, char *const str1, const char *const str2)
{
    int a, b, carry = 0;
    size_t i = strlen( str1 ) - 1;

    while ( i > 0 )
    {
        a = str1[i] - '0';
        b = str2[i] - '0';
        carry += a + b;
        str1[i] = (char)( carry % 2 + '0'); ///convert to character
        carry = carry / 2;
        i--;
    }
    if ( carry )
    {
        dest[0] = '1';
        strcat( dest, str1 );
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I made some changes to your code to reduce it for better reading.